# Why does Tcl expr command returns integers by default?

Tags: tcl

Why does Tcl `expr` command returns integers by default? I have read the [documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/expr.htm) (Section "Types, overflow and precision"), but is there any other way to "make" expr to return float except adding 0.0 to the result and similar?

For example, I'm learning Tcl and I made a simple program to calculate average value:

```
puts -nonewline stdout "Please enter scores: "
flush stdout;
set score [gets stdin];

set sum 0;
set counter 0;

foreach mark $score {
    set sum [expr {$sum + $mark}];
    incr counter;
}

puts "Your average score is: [expr {$sum/$counter}]";
```

As an example:

```
Please enter scores: 1 2 4
Your average score is: 2
```

Otherwise:

```
Please enter scores: 1 2 4.0
Your average score is: 2.333333333333335
```

Is there other way for `expr` to return float, or do I have to insert 0.0, or *.0 here and there to make sure I get result I want? And why is that so?

Comment: Tcl evaluates math expressions in the C runtime, and C math evaluation was defined back when the performance difference between integer and floating point math really mattered. You could say this way of doing it is traditional.

Comment: It does it this way because it is defined to, and has been for decades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any of the numbers in the expression are floats, it will return a float. From the expr man page:

> For arithmetic computations, integers are used until some floating-point number is introduced, after which floating-point is used.

So, you can do something like this:

```
puts "Your average score is: [expr {double($sum)/$counter}]";
```

Another possibility is to make sure that `sum` or `mark` is already a double:

```
set sum 0.0
...
set sum [expr {$sum + $mark}]
```